# Partial view doesn't load inside current view

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, view, partial-views

So I have this partial view:

```
@model QueryQuestionManager.Models.Domain.Answer
<script src="~/Scripts/DynamicList.js"></script>

<div class="editorRow">
@using (Html.BeginCollectionItem("Answers"))
{
    <div>
        @Html.LabelFor(x => x.AnswerText)
        @Html.EditorFor(x => x.AnswerText)
    </div>
    <a href="#" class="deleteRow">delete</a>
}

</div>
```

I want to load this partial view in my main view when someone clicks the link:

```
@model QueryQuestionManager.Models.Domain.Question

@{
ViewBag.Title = "Create";
}

<script src="~/Scripts/DynamicList.js"></script>

<br />
        @using (Html.BeginForm(new { @class = "form", role = "form" }))
        {

            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="editor-label">
                    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.QuestionText)
                </div>

                <div class="form-control">
                    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.QuestionText)
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.QuestionText)
                </div>

                <div class="editor-label">
                    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Category)
                </div>

                <div class="form-control">
                    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Category)
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Category)
                </div>

                <div class="editor-label">
                    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Answers)
                </div>

                <br />
                <div id="editorRows">
                    @foreach (var item in Model.Answers)
                    {
                        @Html.Partial("EditorRow", item);
                    }
                </div>
                @Html.ActionLink("Add another...", "BlankEditorRow",     "Question", new { id = "addItem" })

                <br />

                <input type="submit" value="Save" class="btn btn-success" />
            </div>
        }

<br />
<div>
@Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index", "Home")
</div>
```

This is the action result from the controller

```
public ActionResult BlankEditorRow()
{
    return PartialView("EditorRow", new Answer());
}
```

And then I have a javascript file for the dynamic adding and deleting partial views.

```
$('#addItem').click(function () {
$.ajax({
    url: this.href,
    cache: false,
    success: function (html) {
        $('#editorRows').append(html);
    }
});
return false;
});

$('a.deleteRow').live('click', function () {
    $(this).parents('div.editorRow:first').remove();
    return false;
});
```

But for some reason my partial view doesn't load inside my current view and it opens only the partial view.

[image: How it looks when I click the link]

Am I forgetting something?

Comment: Did you include your unobtrusive-ajax script in your view?  Typically when your partial view ends up on a "new page", it means that the request was successful, but the ajax handler was missing, so it just returns the partial view to a blank new page.  EDIT: just wanted to mention that you could narrow your issue by using the mvc Ajax.ActionLink(...) helper rather than rely upon properly coding a jquery ajax method.

Answer (score 0):

I'm thinking you don't want that action link.  I believe your jQuery click handler has the correct approach, but your action link is linking to your new URL (Question/BlankEditorRow) and you don't want that.  Rather you just need to fetch this html, and insert it as you do, but WITHOUT navigating the main page to that URL.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of the ActionLink, use an anchor tag and a hidden field.

```
<a id="addItem" href="#" />
<input type="hidden" id="partialViewAction" value="@Url.Action("BlankEditorRow","ControllerName")"
```

Now in your ajax call, instead of using the href property of the anchor, use the value of the hidden field.

```
url: $('#partialViewAction').val()
```